# How can i search using a Text box and Listbox in vb.Net?

Tags: vb.net

give me code, in which i can enter a word in a textbox and a listbox appear with a item that has same string in which i enter in a textbox.
Please Help me...

Comment: Yes, the question is badly formed, but this user is new, give him some slack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following via Google, which sound like the type of things you want to do:

1. [Autosearch ListBox in VB.NET
   (WinForms)](http://www.developersdex.com/gurus/code/851.asp)
2. [Search Listboxes as You Type
   (WinForms or is this VB6?)](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/controls/vb_listbox/article.php/c2773/Search-Listboxes-as-you-Type.htm)
3. [Searching for items in a ListBox
   (WPF)](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/12/searching-for-items-in-a-listbox/)

Using # 1, here is some code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    List1.Items.Add("Computer")
    List1.Items.Add("Screen")
    List1.Items.Add("Modem")
    List1.Items.Add("Printer")
    List1.Items.Add("Scanner")
    List1.Items.Add("Sound Blaster")
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Text1.TextChanged
    Dim i As Integer = List1.FindString(Text1.Text)
    List1.SelectedIndex = i
    If Text1.Text = "" Then 
        List1.SelectedIndex = -1 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Comment by anonymous user: When all text of the textbox is cleared, the selection should also be cleared. Add the following code before the last `End Sub` to do so: `If text1.Text = "" Then` (line break) `list1.SelectedIndex = -1` (line break) `End If`.

Answer (score 1):

Think pseudocode, you can do this.
Grab the text from the textbox.
Set a pointer / counter to the listbox and loop through each item until the end of the list.  If the textbox value has the same value as the listboxitem.text then you've found a match exit the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to texboxchange

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.FindString(TextBox1.Text.Trim)
End Sub
```

Comment: add explanation to your answer as that allows op and others to understand the solution as well